# Aligning buffer to an N-byte boundary but not a 2N-byte one?

Tags: c++, c++11, assembly

I would like to allocate some `char` buffers<sup>0</sup>, to be passed to an external non-C++ function, that have a specific alignment requirement.

The requirement is that the buffer be aligned to a `N`-byte<sup>1</sup> boundary, but *not* to a `2N` boundary. For example, if `N` is 64, then an the pointer to this buffer `p` should satisfy `((uintptr_t)p) % 64 == 0` and `((uintptr_t)p) % 128 != 0` - at least on platforms where pointers have the usual interpretation as a plain address when cast to `uintptr_t`.

Is there a reasonable way to do this with the standard facilities of C++11?

If not, is there is a reasonable way to do this outside the standard facilities<sup>2</sup> which works in practice for modern compilers and platforms?

The buffer will be passed to an outside routine (adhering to the C ABI but written in asm). The required alignment will usually be greater than 16, but less than 8192.

Over-allocation or any other minor wasted-resource issues are totally fine. I'm more interested in correctness and portability than wasting a few bytes or milliseconds.

Something that works on both the heap and stack is ideal, but anything that works on either is still pretty good (with a preference towards heap allocation).

---

<sup>0</sup> This could be with `operator new[]` or `malloc` or perhaps some other method that is alignment-aware: whatever makes sense.

<sup>1</sup> As usual, `N` is a power of two.

<sup>2</sup> Yes, I understand an answer of this type causes language-lawyers to become apoplectic, so if that's you just ignore this part.

Comment: Where does `p` come in to this? Are you talking about `p` as in a pointer to the byte buffer?

Comment: Yes, as a practical matter `p` is a pointer the byte buffer (which is why I called it `p`). I was slightly cagey in the actual question by calling `p` an "address" rather than a pointer, because if I called it a pointer a bunch of lawyers would jump down my throat pointing out that arithmetic cannot be done directly on pointers, and going on about the platform-specifics of `intptr_t`, etc.

Comment: Not being aplopectic, the compiler will infer and compute the addresses of the byte allocation buffer at run time, this implies, the OS management of memory. That part of the overall question is missing from the above. What OS are you referring to, also, you seem to have tagged [tag:x86] and [tag:arm] in this, this makes the question inherently vague and broad. Also, another aspect, what compiler chain are you referring to also?

Comment: @t0mm13b - I didn't follow the first part of your last comment regarding "the compiler will infer ... management of memory". I added the `x86` and `arm` tags since those are the platforms I'm most interested in, so if there is a solution of the "not standard, but works in practice variety" I want it to at least work there. I don't think the question is vague because I'm at least asking if there is a standard way to do this, and the "as a practical matter, this works..." part is usually just implied. I shouldn't be punished for mentioning it explicitly.

Comment: @t0mm13b - no specific compiler chain and platform, but I would expect any "non-standard" solution to at be the type of thing that works on _every_ modern platform (ARM, x86, MIPS, SPARC, Power, etc, etc) and compiler (clang, gcc, msvc, icc, miscellaneous boutique compilers).

Comment: the requirement that `(p % 64 == 0) && (p % 128 != 0)` is most peculiar. May I ask where this does come from? In particular the second condition is very odd.

Comment: Compilers and libraries, depending on where the developer's code gets loaded into memory, is deduced and at compile time, in relation to addresses of variables, that will change each time it gets loaded, pointers on other hand, is managed by the runtime, so its not guaranteed to be the same address each time, this also applies for allocated blocks of memory, it can "point" to anywhere provided it is reasonable and not to get out-of-bounds either. So the OS is responsible for dishing out memory to the runtime for usage, *based* on the chipset and OS.

Comment: Either you allocate every time twice the memory you need and then you go hunting for the only address that satisfies your requirement, or you just ask for a big slab of memory at program start and write your own bizarro allocator.

Comment: @t0mm13b - I'm talking about heap-allocated memory. There are already lots of standard and non-standard ways to get _aligned_ heap memory such as `alignas`, `_mm_malloc`, `posix_memalign`, `__declspec(align(...))`, `__attribute__ ((aligned(x)))` and the list goes on. That's well covered in a lot of existing questions, but my question is mostly about how to satisfy the "aligned to N, but not 2N" requirement.

Comment: @Walter - exactly! If that requirement weren't there, this would just be a duplicate of the dozens of existing questions about how to allocate sufficiently aligned memory. The requirement comes from non-functional, performance-related behavior: sometimes you may suffer a large performance degradation when some operation crosses a `N`-byte boundary, but you can't effectively test that if sometimes your buffers are _more aligned_ than you asked for!

Comment: For example, you may suffer a penalty for crossing a 64-byte cache line, but you can't just ask for 64-byte aligned memory and offset from that to get a cache-line crossing operation, since the memory may actually be aligned to 128, 256 or some higher order.

Comment: @MatteoItalia - either would be fine. Is it possible to do it in standard C++?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Logically, to satisfy "aligned to N, but not 2N", we align to `2N` then add `N` to the pointer. Note that this will over-allocate `N` bytes.

So, assuming we want to allocate `B` bytes, if you just want stack space, [`alignas`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/alignas) would work, perhaps.

```
alignas(N*2) char buffer[B+N];
char *p = buffer + N;
```

If you want heap space, [`std::aligned_storage`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/aligned_storage) might do:

```
typedef std::aligned_storage<B+N,N*2>::type ALIGNED_CHAR;
ALIGNED_CHAR buffer;
char *p = reinterpret_cast<char *>(&buffer) + N;
```

I've not tested either out, but the documentation suggests it should be OK.

Comment: I've heard this works only up to 16-byte alignment, so since you are using `N*2` it would work only up to `8-byte alignment` which is pretty useless.

Comment: I don't know what the standard says, but Visual C++ 2017 states it supports [up to 8198 bytes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/cpp/cpp/align-cpp). GNU `g++` seems [to support 128 bytes](https://www.mail-archive.com/gcc-bugs@gcc.gnu.org/msg487113.html).

Comment: @KenY-N: 8192 (1<<13) actually

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`_aligned_malloc(nbytes,alignment)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8z34s9c6.aspx) (in MSVC) or [`_mm_malloc(nbytes,alignment)`](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/523368) (on other compilers) to allocate (on the heap) `nbytes` of memory aligned to `alignment` bytes, which must be an integer power of two.

Then you can use [the trick from Ken's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44232901/) to avoid alignment to `2N`:

```
void*ptr_alloc = _mm_malloc(nbytes+N,2*N);
void*ptr = static_cast<void*>(static_cast<char*>(ptr_alloc) + N);

/* do your number crunching */

_mm_free(ptr_alloc);
```

We must ensure to keep the pointer returned by `_mm_malloc()` for later de-allocation, which must be done via `_mm_free()`.

Comment: Thanks! Is the `static_cast` to and from `void *` legal? Will it return a _resaonable_ value (i.e., at least something within the region of memory pointed to by `ptr_alloc`)?

Comment: The `static_cast` should be legal, why not? It does not change the value of the pointer, but merely changes it's type from `void*` to `char*` so that the pointer arithmetic with `+` works correctly.

Comment: Right, but it was mostly about the cast back and what you can subsequently do with the pointer. There are a lot of caveats around pointer casting and subsequent use in `c++` so my usual assumption is _you can't do that!_ - but I didn't find any particular reference that would say this isn't OK. Thanks!